# How to get index.html.rb to run

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a basic Ruby on Rails server setup.

In routes.rb I have this:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

  root :to => "home#index"
end
```

In my controller/application_controller.rb I have this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
  protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details
end
```

Finally I have /app/views/posts/index.html.erb with some basic HTML in it. How do I get my page to point to that HTML file.

Comment: You can generate posts controller and add index action to it: `rails generate controller  posts index`.  After that index action on posts controller by default will use `app/views/posts/index.html.erb` template.

Comment: Not sure if you mean `localhost:3000/posts` or `<%= link_to "Posts", posts_path` %>

Comment: Let's say I remove the posts folder, how do I make the site go to the HTML.rb page?

Comment: what do you expect your url to look like ? localhost:3000/home ?

Comment: @M.Octavio Yes, and taro I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: what's the name of your main controller? the one that contains what you want to show in your home page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do
  root :to => "main_controller#index"
  match 'home' => 'main_controller#index'
end
```

where main_controller it's the name of the controller that you want to use as main page.

The `match` will allow you to type `localhost:3000/home` and it will do the match with the controller you specified.

You can check your valid routes by running the command `rake routes` it will provide you a list of the routes in your project.

Check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html -5 Inspecting and Testing Routes.